# Error #1009 Cannot find what's causing this null error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs6

I ran into this problem when doing my homework and I can't seem to find a fix, been trying to fix this for 40 mins.

Error

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at portfolio11_fla::MainTimeline/frame4()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
    at portfolio11_fla::MainTimeline/PW()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at portfolio11_fla::MainTimeline/PW()
```

ActionScript3 Code on frame 4

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();
loginBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, PW);
function PW(Event:MouseEvent)
{
    if (enterPW.text == "letmein")
    {
        gotoAndStop(4);
    }
    if (enterPW.text == "home")
        {
            gotoAndPlay(1);
        }
    else
    {
        gotoAndPlay(5);
    }
}
Home2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_4);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Comment: Object IDs don't carry across keyframes. Make sure all the objects you are referencing are on the same frame. That's the best answer I can give without more info.

Comment: Everything I'm doing is on the same frame, still can't figure this out.

Comment: Send your assets in an email (On my profile) and I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: Sending it right now, I fixed most of the things that were popping up now I just have 1 more to fix. Not sure how to fix it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
if (passwordtxtbox.text == "Games")
```

to:

```
else if (passwordtxtbox.text == "Games")
```